# Issues with liquibase migration 2.x to 3.0

Tags: java, liquibase

I am using SQL Server 2012,  and liquibase version 2.0.1 to support databse updates in a Java application(java version 1.7) .

I want to migrate liquibase version to 3.x and I am taking help from [liquibase site](http://www.liquibase.org/v3_upgrade.html)

It says *Liquibase 3.0.0 is a drop-in replacement for any Liquibase 2.0.x version.*

When I replace the existing version with 3.0.0 version jars along with dependencies I get the following error-

```
Liquibase updateSQL Failed: liquibase/database/structure/type/DataType
```

**Detailed Error in Logs :**

```
INFO 3/12/14 3:02 PM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 3/12/14 3:02 PM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
INFO 3/12/14 3:02 PM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
SEVERE 3/12/14 3:02 PM:liquibase: liquibase/database/structure/type/DataType
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/database/structure/type/DataType
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
            at liquibase.change.custom.CustomChangeWrapper.setClass(CustomChangeWrapper.java:84)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.setProperty(XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.java:585)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.setAllProperties(XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.java:517)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.startElement(XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.java:405)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:744)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parse(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:101)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.handleIncludedChangeLog(XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.java:561)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.startElement(XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.java:164)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:775)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
            at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parse(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:101)
            at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:216)
            at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:194)
            at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:253)
            at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:236)
            at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:894)
            at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.database.structure.type.DataType
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
            ... 41 more
```

Comment: Are you calling liquibase by command line? Try the `--version` flag. My guess is that something is mixed up, so that you still call your old version of liquibase but then don't have that version in the classpath (and maybe instead have the new version?)

Comment: @Jens: Yes I am calling it from command line. Let me try --version flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.0 is a drop in replacement from a changelog structure standpoint, but there were some breaking underlying Java API changes which is why there was the version jump from 2.x to 3.x.

http://www.liquibase.org/v3_upgrade.html lists some of the changes but your particular problem seems to be that you have a  class that is using the liquibase.database.structure.type.DataType object that moved to liquibase.structure.core.DataType in 3.0.

If you recompile your custom change classes against liquibase 3.0 the compiler should find this and any other API changes.

Comment: Yes there was one class which was using liquibase.database.structure.type.IntType, recompiling the solutions identified this. Thanks